# remove the cross marks in the image in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on an image processing project which need to remove the cross marks in the ultrasound image first.
I tried all kinds of filters in OpenCV. When the kernel is large, it may remove the marks, but it lost a lot of detail and too blurring.
Here is one example:
[image]

Comment: You can try [inpainting](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html), but without knowledge of what the image is supposed to look under the cross marks, it will only be an approximation.

Comment: you could try something like this for the plus sign https://github.com/marcbelmont/cnn-watermark-removal

Comment: Remove in 2D graphics means replace pixels. Please explain what do you expect to exist in the same places _after_ the crosses are removed, you cannot have holes in an image. Explaining an expected result will help you get an answer.

Comment: Why exactly do yo want to remove the crosses ?

Comment: Thank you guys so much, I'd like to replace the pixels in the cross-marks with the gray values of the near pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach - I'll leave you to fill in the details at the end. I'm basically creating a white cross on a black background and using *"Template Matching"* to find such things in your ultrasound image:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import cv2

# Make a white cross (+ sign) on a black background
cross = np.zeros((10,10), np.uint8)
cross[..., [4,5]] = 255
cross[[4,5], ...] = 255
```

The cross now looks like this:

```
array([[  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

Carrying on with the code:

```
# Load ultrasound image
im = cv2.imread('ultrasound.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Look for crosses
res = cv2.matchTemplate(im, cross, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)

# Contrast stretch
norm = cv2.normalize(res, None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", res)
```

That gives this:

[image]

You can then find the peaks using thresholding like this:

[image]

Draw crosses centred on those points and finally use [in-painting](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html) to fill them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your share. It really helps me a lot.

Comment: Excellent. Note that I did the `cv2.normalize()` to make the brightest point pure white just for display purposes. You don't really want to do that if there are no crosses present in your image, else you will make something else (that is not a cross) into pure white and then assume you do have a cross! So, you should threshold the result image from the template matching and decide if you have a cross before normalising.

Comment: Also, when you are working out where to draw the crosses for in-painting, work out the coordinates and draw the cross temporarily in red on your original image to make sure you get them in the exact correct locations - you may find you are out by half the width of the cross and you are actually centering your cross where the top-left corner should be.... of course, I have never done such a thing ;-)

Comment: Also, I **think** the in-painting changed in v4 of **OpenCV**. I think you used to have to mark what you wanted in black on a white background, but I **think** it may be white marks on black background now. Just watch out!

Comment: Also, your image is JPEG which is really rather nasty for image processing. Have a look at your crosses blown up really large in Photoshop/MS-Paint and you will see they are *blurry* as result of JPEG compression. They are white-is in the middle and black in the corners, but there is a blurry mid-grey line around the white areas. If you can get PNG or TIFF files of the original images you will do better. You could experiment in the code with making the cross somewhat blurry by adding a row/column of `grey128` values around the pure white values and see if template matching finds that better.